# How do I get intent extras from an app that launches another app?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to send data from one app to another. The mother app will launch the child app using this

```
Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.stuff");
LaunchIntent.putExtra("Stuffkey", "blahblah");
startActivity(LaunchIntent);
```

What do I have to write in the child app so that it can read the extra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `getIntent()` in the `onCreate()` method of the main activity of the second app. After that you can call `getStringExtra()` on the intent to get the parameter.

Comment: Yes, I will. There is a waiting period for accepting answers.

Comment: Will it cause an error if the child app is run on its own?

Comment: No, i don't think. In the second app you have to check the return value of getIntent() of course.

Comment: How do you check for getIntent() if it returns null? When I run the child app by itself, it can't check getIntent() since it would return a nullpointerexception.

Comment: You can always call getIntent() in the activity of the second app without problems. You have to check if it returns null.

Comment: I mean that if the child app is run by itself with no intent instantiation, how do you check if there is an intent without directly calling getIntent()?

Comment: When you call startActivity() even if the second app is running, the main activity of the second app will be presented (or presented again) to the user. So your check point is always onCreate().